# Ancient Babylonian problem: solve the system $x + y = 50$, $x^2 + y^2 + (x - y)^2 = 1400$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, math-history

$x + y = 50, x^2 + y^2 + (x - y)^2 = 1400$.  [Hint: Subtract the square of the first equation from twice the second equation to get a quadratic in $x - y$.]  I have gotten it reduced to $x^2 + y^2 -3xy = 550$ but am not sure how to get it in terms of $x - y$ to solve it.

Comment: i know the end answer from my book it ends up being x=30 and y=20.  just dont know what it means by the quadratic in x -y.

Comment: OK, `x^2` and `y^2`, not `x2` and `y2`. That's fine.

Comment: what exactly does it mean by quadratic in x - y in reference to what I have simplified the problem down to so far?

Comment: "quadratic in x-y" means that if you substitute in $z = x - y$, you will get an equation $a z^2 + b z + c = 0$

Comment: Did you try doing exactly what the hint says?

Comment: yeah I simplified it to x^2 + y^2 - 3xy = 550.  I just have to get that into an x - y quadratic, which I am having trouble with seeing clearly.

Comment: Hint: ignore the book's hint, solve for $y$ in the first equation, and plug that into the second to get a quadratic in $x$.

Comment: You must have misunderstood the hint or made an algebra mistake (you should end up with $300$ on the right side, not $550$, and $x^2 + y^2 - 3xy$ isn't right either.

Comment: yeah sorry, mathematical error on my part. It should be x^2 + y^2 - 2xy = 100.  Look better?

Answer (score 2):

The hint is saying that you should take two times $x^2 + y^2 + (x - y)^2$ (the second equation) and subtract the square of the first, $(x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$.
So the result is
$$
2(x^2 + y^2 + (x-y)^2) - (x^2 + 2xy + y^2)
$$
You should be able to simplify this into something simple in terms of just $(x-y)$.  But then, we also know that the above is equal to
$$
2(1400) - (50)^2
$$
So from here you can solve for $x-y$.  Then once you know $x - y$, since you already know $x + y$ you can find out what $x$ and $y$ are individually.

Comment: so I get x^2 + y^2 - 2xy = 100.  In what way can x - y be solved for here? it seems as though I can't really take an x - y out in this equation.

Comment: @D-Man: Factor $x^2-2xy+y^2$.

Comment: ahhh so it factors out to (x-y)(x-y). which equals 100. Same as (x -y)^2 = 100. So, x - y = 10.

Comment: @D-Man Right, but be careful taking a square root - you should have $x - y = \pm 10$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a symmetric system, so it can be reformulated in terms of $x+y=50$ and $xy=?$. Just observe that $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy$.

When we know the sum and product of two numbers, it's easy to find them.

Answer (score 0):

As you have now figured out the answer on your own, I'll post the way I was hinting at in a comment.

I would say your book is pointing you towards the hard way. It's easier just to solve for $y$ in the first equation and substitute that into in the second, giving you a quadratic in $x$, trivially solved by inspection or the quadratic equation.

$$
x + y = 50 \\
y = 50 - x \\
--- \\
x^2 + y^2 + (x - y)^2 = 1400 \\
x^2 + (50-x)^2 + (x - (50 - x))^2 = 1400 \\
x^2 + x^2 - 100x + 50^2 + 4x^2 - 200x + 50^2 = 1400 \\
6x^2 - 300x + 3600 = 0 \\
x^2 - 50x + 600 = 0 \\
(x - 20)(x - 30) = 0 \\
x = 20~or~30\\
y = 50 - x\\
y = 30~or~20
$$

So x and y are 20 and 30, in either combination.

Comment: yeah.  This is obviously the more simple solution.  I guess the book is wanting to do it how the babylonians would have done it? I am not exactly sure.